# Delete message from inbox or sent programmatically in Android lollipop and marshmallow

Tags: android, telephony, android-contentresolver

I want to delete messages of particular contact number programmatically in Android Lollipop and Marshmallow.

I am using the following code to read and delete the messages... but this code does not actually delete messages:

```
public List<Sms> getAllSms() {
    try {
        List<Sms> lstSms = new ArrayList<Sms>();
        Sms objSms = new Sms();
        Uri uriSms = Uri.parse("content://sms/");

        Cursor c = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(uriSms, new String[]{"_id", "thread_id", "address", "person", "date", "body"}, null, null, null);

        getActivity().startManagingCursor(c);
        int totalSMS = c.getCount();
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < totalSMS; i++) {
                long id = c.getLong(0);
                long threadId = c.getLong(1);
                String address = c.getString(2);
                String body = c.getString(5);
                String date = c.getString(3);

                Log.e("log>>>",
                    "0--->" + c.getString(0) + "1---->" + c.getString(1)
                            + "2---->" + c.getString(2) + "3--->"
                            + c.getString(3) + "4----->" + c.getString(4)
                            + "5---->" + c.getString(5));
                Log.e("log>>>", "date" + c.getString(0));

                if (address.equals("1234567890")) {
                    // mLogger.logInfo("Deleting SMS with id: " + threadId);

                    getContext().getContentResolver().delete(
                        Uri.parse("content://sms/" + id), null, null);

                    Log.e("log>>>", "Delete success.........");
                }
                c.moveToNext();
            }
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("You have no SMS ");
        }
        c.close();
        return lstSms;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Manifest permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
```

Please help me regarding to delete the messages.

OR

suggest me a way to do the following:

If I send message in background programatically in both the above Android version then it should not save messages in sent folder or anywhere in the device.

Answer (score 4):

> i want to delete message of particular contact number programmatically in android lollipop and marshmallow

You will need to write a complete SMS client.

You cannot implement an app that only deletes messages on API Level 19 and higher. The user will not make your app be the default SMS app on the device. If your app is not the default SMS app, then "your app is not able to write to the SMS Provider for other operations, such as to mark messages as draft, mark them as read, delete them, etc." See [this official blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/10/getting-your-sms-apps-ready-for-kitkat.html) for more.

> Tell me the way that if i send message in background programatically in both the above android version. then it should not save in sent folder or anywhere in the device

The decision of what happens with sent SMS messages is made between Android, the user's default SMS client, and possibly the user. You do not get a vote.